# Why can't my code get MainModule of the current process?

Tags: c#, .net, process, windows-server-2008, access-denied

I have the following code that is being run from under a local user that belongs to `Users` group:

```
String processName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName;
```

that fails with `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` claiming that `Access is denied` with the following stack:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
```

Now [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainmodule%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) has "community content" at the bottom of the page saying that this behavior is observed when code is being called by an elevated process or from under another user because it will try to open the process.

Okay, it tries to open that process, but the code is running under a user belonging to `Users` group, why is it denied access to open the process?